# django views many-to-many relationship field problem

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-queryset

During work on my 1st app(kind of cookery book where it will be possible also to create meal plans) i have a problem to addapt one field from many-to-many(through) model to my html template. Field name is 'meal' in RecipeMealPlan model.

Here are my models:

```
class Recipe(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    cooking_time = models.IntegerField(help_text='in minutes', validators=[MinValueValidator(1), MaxValueValidator(5000)])
    difficulty_level = models.IntegerField(choices=DIFFICULTY_LEVELS, default=1)
    description = models.TextField()
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    cuisine = models.ForeignKey('Cuisine', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    ingredient = models.ManyToManyField(Ingredient, through='IngredientRecipe')
    meal_plan = models.ManyToManyField('MealPlan', through='RecipeMealPlan')
    
class RecipeMealPlan(models.Model):
    recipe = models.ForeignKey(Recipe, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    meal_plan = models.ForeignKey('MealPlan', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    meal = models.IntegerField(choices=MEALS)

    MEALS = (
        (1, 'Breakfast'),
        (2, '2nd breakfast'),
        (3, 'Lunch'),
        (4, 'Snack'),
        (5, 'Dinner')
    )

class MealPlan(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    amount = models.IntegerField(validators=[MinValueValidator(4), MaxValueValidator(6)])
```

Here is my view created to show mealplan details on my app:

```
class MealPlanDetailsView(View):
    def get(self, request, id):
        mealplan = MealPlan.objects.get(id=id)
        recipes = mealplan.recipe_set.all()
        return render(request, 'diet_app/mealplan_details.html', {'mealplan': mealplan, 'recipes': recipes})
```

And html template:

```
    {% extends 'diet_app/base.html' %}
    {% block title %}{{ mealplan|upper }}{% endblock %}
    {% block content %}
                    <h2>{{ mealplan|upper }}</h2>
                    <ul> <p>Posiłki:</p>
                    {% for recipe in mealplan.recipemealplan_set.all %}
                        <li>{{ recipe.get_meal_display}}: <a href="/recipe/{{recipe.id}}/">{{ recipe }}</a></li>
                    {% endfor %}
                    </ul>
    {% endblock %}
```

Everything looks fine but link to receipe details doestnt work:

```
<a href="/recipe/{{recipe.id}}/">
```

Link works if i write the loop like this:

```
{% for recipe in recipes %}
<li><a href="/recipe/{{recipe.id}}/">{{ recipe.title }} </a></li>
{% endfor %}
```

But then i dont see meal name before recipe (meal name means Breakfast, dinner etc.). I don't how to write it down to see together meal name and recipe with link to recipe details.

I succeed only when i wrote those 2 loops combined but then i see my meal plan repeated few times.

Any ideas what should i do to make it work the way i want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`recipe.id` is the id of the through model `RecipeMealPlan`, and not `Recipe`, so instead of `recipe.id`, you need to use `recipe.recipe.id`.

Also for sanity's sake, you could use something like `recipemealplan` instead of `recipe` as the variable name, so:

```
    {% for recipemealplan in mealplan.recipemealplan_set.all %}
        <li>{{ recipemealplan.get_meal_display}}: <a href="/recipe/{{ recipemealplan.recipe.id }}/">{{ recipemealplan }}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
```